# jQuery click event not firing for anchor when contained within slickgrid cell

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, jquery, slickgrid

I have slickgrid setup to use the `RowSelectionModel` along with a column containing a hyperlink setup using a customFormatter (lightly modded to protect the innocent):

```
function linkFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return "<a href='#' rel='XYZ'>View</a>";
}
```

Using the following click event handler:

```
$('a[rel=XYZ]').on('click',function (e) {
    $(this).replaceWith('some html');
});
```

The above handler never fires for links within the grid.  If I create the link outside slickgrid it works fine indicating my selector and function are valid.

If I hook a JavaScript function into the `<a>` tag it works fine but I'd really rather keep my js unobtrusive.  Any recommendations on what I can do to get the click handler firing for hyperlinks embedded within a slickgrid cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('PARENT_ELEMENT').on('click','a[rel=XYZ]',function (e) {
    $(this).replaceWith('some html');
});
```

Just make sure that `'PARENT_ELEMENT'` exist when you bind your event. Safest way is to use `'body'` or `document` as `'PARENT_ELEMENT'`.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used slickgrid, but I suspect you're attaching your event handler before the grid is populated. Is there an `onGridDataLoaded` or similar event you can hook into?

The example [here](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html) uses something like:

```
loader.onDataLoaded.subscribe(function () {
    // rewire handlers
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by Tim you can use samething like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[rel=XYZ]', function (e) {
    $(this).replaceWith('some html');
});
```

Comment: ofc on needs to be attached to an existing element in the DOM to work against newly added elements!  My new problem is this kind of works but I need to click the link twice for it to fire, but at least this is a step forward.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you provide a jsfiddle? see this http://jsfiddle.net/D9TYR/7/

Comment: Looks like an issue with the checkboxselectcolumn plugin I'm using.  Fork with the plugin added http://jsfiddle.net/MA9nt/

Comment: try using mousedown event instead of click